# Handling error with RxSwift and MVVM

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I am trying to put together a nice architecture with RxSwift and MVVM. I am wondering how to handle the errors coming from observables correctly.

My ViewModel looks like:

```swift
class MapViewModel {

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    private let listObservable: Observable<[MyObject]>

    let list: Variable<[MyObject]>
    let showError: Variable<Bool>

    init() {
        self.listObservable = getObservable().shareReplay(1)

        self.list = Variable<[MyObject]>([])
        self.listObservable
            .bind(to: list)
            .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)

        self.showError = Variable<Bool>(false)
        self.listObservable
            .subscribe(
                onError: { [weak self] error in
                    print("Error downloading: \(error)")
                    self?.showError.value = true
            }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }
}
```

I thought it was to correct way to do it: clean separation of concerns, and shared observable to prevent calling the REST endpoint multiple times.

However when I do this - and the observable sends an error - I get a fatalError from RxSwift because the error is not handled in the `bind()` call.

To fix this, I changed the code to:

```swift
self.listObservable
    .subscribe(
        onNext: { [weak self] list in
            self?.list.value = list
        },
        onError: { [weak self] error in
            print("Error downloading: \(error)")
            self?.showError.value = true
    }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

This seems less clear for me. What should be the correct approach with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `Variable`s is throwing you off I think. Avoid them when possible.

My impression of this code:

- When the view model is created, it makes a call `getObservable()`.
- There is no provision for input from the user.
- The `showError` variable seems to be getting used as a trigger rather than to actually pass a value so it should be Void instead of Bool

I would expect this view model to look more like:

```
struct MapViewModel {
    let list: Observable<[MyObject]>
    let showError: Observable<Void>

    init() {
        let dataResult = getObservable()
            .materialize()
            .shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()
        list = dataResult.map { $0.element }
            .filter { $0 != nil }
            .map { $0! }
        showError = dataResult.map { $0.error }
            .filter { $0 != nil }
            .map { _ in }
    }
}
```

The secret sauce in the above is the use of `materialize` to convert the error into an `onNext` event so you can use it for the trigger.

The subscribes/binds and dispose bag should be in the view controller, not in the view model.

Comment: There was an error in my sample code. I updated it to reflect that I was using `listObservable` is both cases. Thanks for the answer, I replaced the `Variable`s by `Observable`s.

Comment: @DanielT. Why avoid `Variable`s when possible? Because your adding more state? I have a View Model with quite a few `outputs` corresponding to each `IBOutlet` property In `View Controller`. This also allows me to avoid a bunch of optional `observables`. Is this an instance where it is appropriate to use `Variable`s?

Comment: Well a `Variable` is better than an optional observable... And using them is IMHO a good way to break into Rx, but you are breaking the declarative nature of Rx by using them. Here is one of the many articles discussing it: http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx